# If I leave my job, must I turn over self-made documents/contacts?

Tags: professionalism

If I leave my job, must I turn over self-made documents/contacts?

I've spent far too much energy thinking things would pay off, but my employer just doesn't care; I don't feel they understand what I do for them or deserve having me just hand in all of my personal & professionally put together data.

Anyone experience similar? Tips? Thoughts?

Comment: Were the documents produced on the job? Using any employer-supplied resources?

Comment: You need to be very careful of _commercial-in-confidence_ and _confidentiality agreements_.  If you are considering taking resources and contacts from your current employer and go into business in competition, I am rather sure that they will take a very dim view of that.

Comment: What are these documents? Did you write your own summary of a language or framework you'll be able to use in the future, or do they describe a project the company is doing? Did you write them on company time? Were you told (or did you sign) that everything you create belongs to the company (the norm where I work.) When you "turn something over" do you no longer have a copy? This question needs far more detail to be answerable. Please edit it.

Comment: Do you have a reason to keep them? Or do you have a reason to keep them _from_ the employer other than "meh"?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Some, but mostly with my own computer and on my time at home.

Comment: @JaneS Thank you. I don't plan on doing anything with the information. I just can't seem to justify giving more of my hard work to an entity that doesn't give back any.

Comment: @rath less "meh" and more "they treated me so bad, and I don't know why my above and beyond should just be handed over because I'm leaving"?

Comment: @mac Thank you for responding. Bad behaviour of others doesn't excuse the same from you. That's too short to be an answer, but that would be mine.

Comment: Note that in many jobs, especially technical jobs, work done in personal time still belongs to the company. Read your contract. If that's what you signed, that's your answer.

Comment: @keshlam Where do you get that idea? Can you give a resource so that others may read about this concept?

Comment: My contract. Many other contracts. Past discussion here and elsewhere. _Know what you are signing, keep a copy, and abide by it unless you're willing to argue the matter in court -- remembering that they can usually afford better lawyers._

Answer (score 5):

Please note that I am not a lawyer. If you are concerned, seek professional, qualified legal advice.

> If I leave my job, must I turn over self-made documents/contacts?

Generally speaking, **all intellectual property you create during the course of your employment is owned by your employer**. The phrase "course of your employment" generally means during company time, using company resources or what your superiors have directed you to do. This includes software, documents and contact details of those you deal with. Your employment contract and/or country/state laws may have additional stipulations or exclusions.

There may also have additional confidentiality agreements, non-disclosure agreements or non-poaching agreements between you and your employer or your employer and other parties that may also affect you. Ask your employer for copies of these.

Also remember to stop using any company provided resources (e.g. laptop, E-mail, company phone). Physical goods should be returned to your employer.

**Anything you create outside your employment is generally yours**. Even if your contract states that everything you create is your employer's, many states and countries have limits on this. Your employer may demand access to them all they wish but, unless there is a contract or other agreement stating otherwise, it is yours.

It is best to hand over anything you think is relevant and walk away. If you do not, your employer may go to court to request you hand over any missing documents - an expense and time commitment most people want to avoid.

While that may seem to be a lot, **having someone's phone number does not create a relationship and having a document does not give someone understanding**. I do not know how much time and effort you put into things and it can seem like walking away gives your employer everything. However, particularly in some cultures, the loss of a key contact can be very significant. People are not stupid and, if they see you walking away, they will ask questions.

Meanwhile, it is important to **keep things professional even when you feel your employer is not acting professionally or disrespects you**. Bad mouthing previous employers to your contacts or in future job interviews does not convey a positive impression no matter how justified you feel.

If you think you are close to seeing a pay off, perhaps delay your leaving. Look for new roles in the meantime, as it may take time to find a new position, but keep an open mind. A management or direction change within the organization can turn the whole thing around.

Comment: not to be pedantic, but if you meant "not" in the first sentence, "now" rather reverses the meaning, and while many people will guess it's a typo, some might not, particularly if English isn't their first language.

Comment: This is remarkably close to legal advice.  Is there any way you can really shorten it up, covering in very broad strokes the most essential concepts? And then refer the question to some more in-depth on-line resources?

Comment: @AndyzSmith I tried to bold the main points. The problem with linking to on-line resources is most of them are country-specific. This question is really too broad to answer in this format.

Comment: Certainly.  The poster has to refine in several ways for this to be any kind of useful and general purpose Q&A record.  I'd just be looking to be even more general, and try to dig down into the fundamental principle behind these often different implementations.  E.G. Employers pay for your time and it is often very difficult to determine what you did on your time and what you did on their time, and so there are lots of rules.